# Trying to use "import twilio" instead of "from twilio import twiml"

Tags: python, twilio

This works:

```
from twilio import twiml
r = twiml.Response()
```

but

```
import twilio
r = twilio.twiml.Response()
```

fails with

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'twiml'
```

Why?  And how can I avoid using "from twilio import stuff"?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to import the submodule, too:

```
import twilio.twiml
```

Comment: Right. Only if the top-level twilio module imports twiml will it be available they way OP wants it.

Answer (score 2):

`from twilio import twiml` only works if `twiml` is in the `twilio` module's namespace.  If it's simply `twiml.py` inside the `twilio` directory, it's in the `twilio` *package*, but it won't be in the `twilio` *module* unless the `twilio` module imports it in its `__init__.py`.

with all that background information, I think the one-liner you're looking for is this:

```
import twilio.twiml as twiml
```

This will look for `twiml` in the `twilio` package, then bring it into your namespace as `twiml`.